# How to track all shortcut keys pressed and the process they interact with?

Tags: logs, keyboard-shortcuts, monitoring, tail, tabs

For a while now and for some reason I find myself in the unpleasant situation of Ctrl-w not working anymore in any program, which means I need the mouse any time I want to close a tab.

I tried checking general Debian keyboard shortcuts, input method shortcuts etc. but didn't find any conflict so far. However, it's not like there's zero reaction. When I press Ctrl-w in Firefox for example, the vertical scrollbar on the right gets highlighted until I release the keys. In Kate, the cursor stops blinking for an instant.

So the strategy I came up with is somehow finding a log which tells me which program or process is being triggered by any keypress (or just shortcuts would do fine)...

I found out all keys pressed can be logged using programs like KeyLogger or logkeys ; but they don't seem to make a link to the action triggered by those keypresses...

Is there a way to track any activity triggered by the keys I press in Debian 10 AVL-MXE? Like tail but realtime (or non-realtime) monitoring/logging of anything I'm doing?

Or another way to solve my "Ctrl-w not working anymore" problem?

Thanks so much for any clue!

some system info:
Kernel      : Linux 5.9.1-rt20avl1 (x86_64)
Version     : #1 SMP PREEMPT_RT Sat Oct 31 12:21:58 EDT 2020
C Library       : GNU C Library / (Debian GLIBC 2.28-10) 2.28
Distribution        : Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the answer to my question, but I did find a simple solution to my problem. Instead of using Ctrl-w to close tabs, I now simply use Alt-f-c. Admitted, it's one key more to press, but it also allows me to close tabs with one hand from my keyboard. It also helped me realize that preconfigured Menu shortcuts are underrated, or at least that I didn't realize how handy they can be for repeated actions. Hope this is a useful thought :)